# How big can a subspace of $U\otimes V$ be if it contains no non-zero "pure" tensors?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, tensor-products

Someone asked me a question involving bilinear forms today, and I was able to reformulate it into the following question.

Given finite dimensional vector spaces $U$ an $V$ over a field $k$, define a pure tensor $U\otimes V$ to be an element of the form $u\otimes v$, or alternatively, an element of $$P=\left(\bigcup_{u\in U}ku\otimes V\right)\cup \left(\bigcup_{v\in V} U\otimes kv\right).$$

What is the maximum dimension of a linear subspace $W\subset U\otimes V$ such that $W\cap P=\{0\}$?

Since $P$ is only the union of subspaces but not actually a subspace itself, this appears not to be strictly a problem of linear algebra.  The answer apparently depends on the base field, so I am mostly interested in $k=\mathbb C$, but an answer that can explain why the answer is different over $\mathbb R$ would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\dim(U) = m$ and $\dim(V) = n$, the question reduces to the maximal dimension of $W \subset U \otimes V$ such that
$$
\mathbb{P}^{m-1} \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1} = \mathbb{P}(U) \times \mathbb{P}(V) \subset \mathbb{P}(U \otimes V) = \mathbb{P}^{mn-1}
$$
does not intersect $\mathbb{P}(W)$. If the dimension of $\mathbb{P}(W)$ is at least
$$
(mn-1) - (m-1) - (n-1) = (m-1)(n-1)
$$
then the intersection is nonempty by Bezout theorem. Otherwise, it is empty for general $W$. So, the maximal dimension is $\dim(\mathbb{P}(W)) = (m-1)(n-1) - 1$, or equivalently, $\dim(W) = (m-1)(n-1)$.

Comment: I'm curious about the case where $k$ isn't algebraically closed; any ideas?  Obv Bezout uses it.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$ one can find $W$ of higher dimension, at least in some cases. For instance, let $m = n = 2$. Then we are talking about the Segre quadric $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^3$. Its equation is $xw - yz = 0$ in appropriate coordinates, the signature of this quadratic form is $(2,2)$, so if you take a 2-dimensional subspace on which this quadratic form is definite, the intersection is empty.